# How to start close application and restart after click on Notificaton?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-pendingintent

In my application i get notification and if the user click on the notification the app should start.
if the app already opened and the user click on the notification. the app open again but twice.

Now, the idea is that i need to call `refreshActionBarSpinner()` when the app is started.
the `refreshActionBarSpinner()` method is in `MainActivity.class -> onStart()`.

1. if i'm using `PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` the app is started but
   onStart() doesn't called.
2. if i'm using `PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext , MainActivity.class), 0);` the app opened twice

this the full code:

```
 Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent openAppOnClick = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.workcloc_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setContentIntent(openAppOnClick)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(content))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(UNIQ_ID_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

So, what I need is: if the app already opend in background then call the `refreshActionBarSpinner()` and if it doesn't just open the app.
How can i do it please?

I noticed that if i using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` its works great!
it's recommended?

Answer (score 0):

If an existing activity responds to a new intent, then [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) will be called. If you want `refreshActionBarSpinner()` to be called in that instance, you should add a call to it in the `onNewIntent()` callback.

Comment: If i using "android:launchMode="singleTop" it's works. But it's ok?

Comment: Yeah, that would do the same thing as having the single top intent flag.

Comment: Ops, I meant SingleInstance sorry. It's still ok?

Comment: If you want to use single instance, you should review the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) documentation and test navigation between activities.